# Google fusiontables sql OR clause

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables, google-query-language

I m trying the sample at

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/gviz_datatable

---

In the query, instead of

query += " WHERE 'Scoring Team' = '" + team + "'";

---

i tried to add another OR condition...

query += " WHERE 'Scoring Team' = '" + team + "' or 'Receiving Team'='Mexico' ";

This would return an error

---

While if i use AND

query += " WHERE 'Scoring Team' = '" + team + "' and 'Receiving Team'='Mexico' ";

There would not return error.

---

Why would the OR condition return error?
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `OR` - operator is not supported by the FusionTables-API.

It may be hard to believe, but that's how it is.

Comment: yes... it is not supported... https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference thanks for answer!